# adding an input value and submitting the form on load

Tags: javascript, forms

I have the following form:

```
<form action="http://example.co.uk/order" method="post" id="voucher" class="AVAST_PAM_nonloginform">
  <fieldset>
    <h4>Vouchers</h4>
    <input type="text" class="discount_name form-control" id="discount_name" name="discount_name" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitDiscount">
    <button type="submit" name="submitAddDiscount" class="button btn btn-default button-small"><span>OK</span></button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and am using the following script:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById(\"discount_name\").value = \"50681\";
}
</script>
```

to populate the input. I then use:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.forms['voucher'].submit();
}
</script>
```

to activate the submit.

However, use the second script, it stops the "50681" from being inputted into the text box (instead submits a blank input).

Originally I had the code as :

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById(\"discount_name\").value = \"50681\";
document.forms['voucher'].submit();
    }
    </script>
```

(I split it up thinking it may be a timing issue).

Any ideas?

p.s. the reason for the backslash's is due to it currently being run under php until I can get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with `(\"discount_name\").value = \"50681\";` & `document.forms['voucher'].submit();`

In either of the case you can avoid `\` & for form you need to target by the `index` number. Assuming there is only one form present , so passing `0` in index

```
 window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("discount_name").value = "50681";
    document.forms[0].submit();
    }
```

Note: In the demo I have changed the action url to `https` else it will prohibit to make call from jsfiddle. In your case you can still keep `http` in code

[**DEMO USING ID**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfm8hfsp/1/)

Comment: the "\" is because its running in php for now.
It's prestashop and there is multiple forms. How do I find out the index number?

Comment: for multiple form you ca target using id

Comment: Can you update your example please to reflect using ID?